# Como usar google Charts Offline?

Tags: html, css, aplicação-web, google

Eu já usei o charts e ainda penso em usá-lo num sistema que estou desenvolvendo!
Só que esse sistema vai rodar off!

Existe alguma biblioteca ou algum jeito de usar o Google Charts Offline ?

Comment: Talvez não seja a resposta que tu procura, mas como Google Charts não tem como usar off, dá uma olhada em http://www.chartjs.org/

Comment: Valeu irmão, ajudou demais!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No link abaixo, diz que não é permitido utilizar offline.

Fonte: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/faq

Trecho que fala isto:

> Can I use charts offline?
>
> Your users' computers must have access to
>   https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js in order to use the
>   interactive features of Google Charts. This is because the
>   visualization libraries that your page requires are loaded dynamically
>   before you use them. The code for loading the appropriate library is
>   part of the included script, and is called when you invoke the
>   google.charts.load() method. Our terms of service do not allow you to
>   download the google.charts.load or google.visualization code to use
>   offline.

Comment: Realmente mano! Passei nesse FAQ e não enxerguei isso! Valeu!